# How to get message for aborted or failed transactions on Paypal?

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am using Paypal Express Checkout with NVP API on my magento 1.9 store.  I want to know when a customer redirects from my store to Paypal's website to do payment, how can I get any message in my Paypal dashboard or somewhere that the customer actually didn't tried out payment or something else broke down?

I tried a transaction and got "SetExpressCheckout" result with response but I could not complete due to the fact I could not use the credit card but it didn't give any notification for this in my Paypal account or magento store.

How can I get such notifications/failure messages too?

Comment: After SetExpressCheckout, I get the response with a "Token", "Correlationid".  But do not get "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" request further.  So, how can I check the status of a transaction with correlationid.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the debug logs in System->Configuration-> Payment Methods. Under each Paypal option is a section called Advanced Settings that you can expand, looks something like this http://xomf.com/rcvll

The Paypal logs should record the request/response going out to Paypal.  You might also need your server access logs depending on the issue.